# Pandas groupby date and find date with max count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm learning python and pandas.

I have the following dataframe

```
Date         Category    Sales       Paid
8/12/2020    Table       1 table     Yes
8/12/2020    Chair       3chairs     Yes
13/1/2020    Cushion     8 cushions  Yes
24/5/2020    Table       3Tables     Yes
31/10/2020   Chair       12 Chairs   No
11/7/2020    Mats        12Mats      Yes
11/7/2020    Mats        4Mats       Yes
```

I need to extract the quantity from the sales column which I learned is through this:

```
df['Sales'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
```

I then feel I need to group by date

```
df['Sales'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).groupby(df['Date'])
```

After which I then need to sum all the counts within each group

```
df['Sales'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).groupby(df['Date']).agg(sums='count')
```

Now I'm stuck, I want to find the date with most events (counts). How do I do that? When I run max()

```
df['Sales'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).groupby(df['Date']).agg(sums='count').max()
```

I don't see anything except the same values as the count command. How do I solve this?

Comment: Use `idxmax` instead `max`